# python: reverse the elements of magic methods that affect operators

Tags: python, python-3.x, addition, magic-methods

i am trying, just for exercise, to create a python object that can contain a number with arbitrary decimals. Everything works fine but i'm having problems with making the object interact with mathematical operators. This is how you can reproduce the error:

```py
class Value():
  def __init__(self,value):
    self.value = value
  def __add__(self,other):
    return self.value + other

x = Value(5)
print(x+2) # this works fine: 7
print(2+x) # this doesn't work: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Value'
```

the same thing happens with all the other mathematic operations, is there something i can do to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed implementing `__radd__`:

```
class Value():
  def __init__(self,value):
    self.value = value
  def __add__(self,other):
    return self.value + other
  __radd__ = __add__

x = Value(5)
print(x+2)
# 7
print(2+x)
# 7
```

---

More on it in the Python docs discussing [emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) and the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module.

Comment: thanks for you answer, you know if there is a similar magic method for the other operators?... (-,@,*...)

Comment: @Giuppox yes, see the relevant links to the official docs

Answer (score 3):

Implement [`__radd__` (or other `__r*` methods)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__):

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.value + other

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.value + other


x = Value(5)
print(x + 2)
print(2 + x)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `__radd__`, `__r*__` methods are python magic methods that make an object make something when is taken from the `__add__` of another object.
Try with something like this.

```
class Value(): 
   def __init__(self,value): 
      self.value = value 
   def __add__(self,other): 
      return self.value + other 
   __radd__ = __add__ 

x = Value(5) 
print(x+1 == 1+x) // True
```